# Small font in react-devtools

Tags: react-native, react-devtools

I am getting really small font after opening react-devtools on ubuntu 16.04.
https://github.com/facebook/react-devtools/tree/master/packages/react-devtools

[image]

You can see comparison of the react-devtools and 'normal' font size in the screen above.

ctrl+ is not working, I cannot increase the font size, but I can decrease it (Ctrl-) and go back to default size (Ctrl o)